# Moving Mysql database after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, mysql, copy

I have an old database I want to use. However, I have upgraded Ubuntu twice since last time I touched the database.Last Ubuntu upgrade included installation on a new disk. So I have an old version of the database on another disk in the system.
I have copied the files, run musql_upgrade and restarted mysqld. Now I can open the database and I can list the tables, but if I try e.g. select count(*) from med15; I am told that the table does not exist.
What is the problem? Can anybody help?

Comment: You used the word "copied". To my knowledge you can't simply copy the files back. You need to first "export" the database and then "import" it. (I assume it is too late for that now.) To accomplish that task of, you can use either "mysqldump" or "phpmyadmin" . To facilitate restoring a database, I run an automated "mysqldump" prior to all backups.

Comment: Thank you for the reponse. I am now working to get the old system up to -anddo a dump to import on the new system. At the moment I assume that that is the shortest way to success.

Comment: So what happened?